О переходе прилагательных из разряда в разряд
В сочетании "живой солдат", употребленном в значении "не мертвый", прилагательное "живой" является относительным или качественным?

Лично я не могу сказать "очень живой солдат" или "очень мертвый солдат", "самый живой солдат", "самый мертвый солдат". Если я употребляю такие конструкции, то я имею в виду непрямое значение данного слова - "активный, деятельный, жизнерадостный". Стало быть, в сочетании "живой солдат" перед нами относительное прилагательное, возникшее из качественного?

Живой  — многозначное слово (7 значений).  В многозначных словах указаны слова с разным значением, но эти значения связаны между собой, поэтому слова объединены в одной словарной статье. Нас интересуют значения 1 и 3.
ЖИВОЙ, -ая, -ое; жив, -а, -о; живейший. 1. Такой, который 
живёт, обладает жизнью (противоп.: мёртвый). Ж. организм. Ж. 
человек. 3. Полный жизненных сил; жизнерадостный. Ж. 
ребёнок. Ж-ая натура. Ж. темперамент. 

В словарях написано, что живой — качественное прилагательное во всех значениях. В то же время качество проявляется по-разному.
В значении 1 живой — это обладающий жизнью, то есть особыми признаками материи.  Из качественных признаков краткая форма и наличие антонима.
ЖИЗНЬ, -и; ж. 1. Особая форма существования материи, 
возникающая на определённом этапе её развития, основным 
отличием которой от неживой природы является обмен веществ. 
Возникновение жизни на земле. Ж. растительного мира. Законы 
жизни. 

В значении 3 качественный признак выражен более явно, в том числе это сравнительная степень,  возможность иметь наречие (степень признака), а также  способность вступать в однородные отношения с прилагательными:
Он был чрезвычайно подвижный, живой, любезный господин, словом, «милый малый» и ничего больше. Активный, живой, подвижный ребенок – норма, и таких детей большинство.

Я открывала еще универсальный словарь русского языка Морковкина, там написано, что вообще относительным это слово быть не может.

Морковкину, конечно, виднее)  Остается узнать, почему не может. Если есть убедительные доказательства,  то придется согласиться. Краткая форма вот есть, антоним, может быть.  // Мне кажется, что качество  можно измерить, а здесь ничего такого нет. Если только вот Ленин живее всех живых. // Может быть, саму жизнь считают качеством.  Тогда живой – это обладающий особыми свойствами материи.  Пойдет такое качественное определение?

Обычно качественные имеют антонимы.

Так мы же с вами решили, что это качественное прилагательное, против Морковкина не пойдешь)  Слова жить, живой, жизнь взаимосвязаны,  определяются в словаре одно через другое, и у них общее качество – особая форма органической материи
